# How to show a video from gallery in Ionic iOS

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, html5-video

I am using html5's video tag to show a video I select from the gallery. I'm getting an issue where the video doesn't load even though I've provided a source.

This is an Ionic/Angular project with Capacitor as the bridge, but still using Cordova plugins. Here is a prototype of my code:

**my-page.page.ts**

```
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage {

  // ... some code which gets the a reference to the video element from the template

  // this function is called when the user clicks a button to choose video from gallery
  onPickVideo() {
    const cameraOptions: CameraOptions = {
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.VIDEO,
    };
    this.camera.getPicture(cameraOptions).then(videoUri => {
      console.log(videoUri);
      this.videoSrc = Capacitor.convertFileSrc(videoUri);
      console.log(this.videoSrc);
      this.videoEl.load();
      this.videoEl.currentTime = 0.1;
    });
  }
}
```

**my-page.page.html**

```
<video playsinline #video>
  <source [src]=".videoSrc" type="video/mp4" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

The output of my-page.page.ts is:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7D85727C-CE9A-4816-BC42-C97F03AFDEB4/tmp/F6DCE819-ED4A-41E4-BAFB-814500F2FB27.MOV

capacitor://localhost/_capacitor_file_/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7D85727C-CE9A-4816-BC42-C97F03AFDEB4/tmp/F6DCE819-ED4A-41E4-BAFB-814500F2FB27.MOV
```

**This works on desktop and on Android**. It's not working on iPhone 6 with iOS 12. Untested on other iOS versions.

Some things I've tried:

- Added NSCameraUsageDescription, NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription, NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription, NSMicrophoneUsageDescription
- Used [src]= in the video tag, and removed the source tag. Or omitting the 'video/mp4' type
- Running in live reload mode vs just building.
- Chopping `'file:///'` off the start of `videoUri` before passing it to `convertFileSrc()`. Or doing the former and directly setting it to videoSrc without using `convertFileSrc()` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by "sanitizing" the URL. I'm yet to learn what that really means. Here is the code in case anyone needs it

```
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';


@Component({...})
export class MyPage {

  // ... some code which gets the a reference to the video element from the template

  safeUrl: SafeUrl;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  // this function is called when the user clicks a button to choose video from gallery
  onPickVideo() {
    const cameraOptions: CameraOptions = {
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.VIDEO,
    };
    this.camera.getPicture(cameraOptions).then(videoUri => {
      this.safeUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(
          Capacitor.convertFileSrc(videoUri)
        );
      this.videoEl.load();
      this.videoEl.currentTime = 0.1;
    });
  }
}
```

Then make sure to be using safeUrl in the template `[src]="safeUrl"`.